# org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils - change text encodig

Tags: java, rtf, fileutils

I have one file which contains text(ukranian symbols). Example: `${name} - привіт`. I need to replace from `${name}` to `Саша`. But in output file I recive 
something like this: `Ð¿Ñ??Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ - привіт` instead of `Саша- привіт`. But if I use .txt instead .rtf - all is fine. I understand the problem in the coding but can't solve it.

Code example:

```
File file = new File("original.rtf");
String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);

content = content.replace("${name}", "Саша");

File fileNew = new File("changed.rtf");
FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(fileNew);

byte[] contentInBytes = content.getBytes("UTF-8");
fop.write(contentInBytes);
fop.flush();
fop.close();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString%28java.io.File%29

> Deprecated. 2.5 use [readFileToString(File, Charset)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) instead

Also, make sure that the java compiler is reading your Java source with the same encoding as it is stored in (UTF-8 recommended), with the `-encoding` switch.